# Different content for each "::before" pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, css-content

How can we give different content to each `::before` pseudo-element? My code looks like this:

```css
.timeline h1::before {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: inherit;
  left: 0;
}

.timeline h1:first-of-type:before {
  content: '01';
  color: #E82F3A;
}

.timeline h1:nth-of-type(2):before {
  content: '02';
  color: #E82F3A;
}

.timeline h1:last-of-type:before {
  content: '03';
  color: #E82F3A;
}

.timeline h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: #404C60;
  padding-left: 35px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the first `<h1>`'s `::before` pseudo-element to have content '01', the second's to have content '02', and the last's to have content '03'. But when I try the code, all the `<h1>`'s `::before` content is '03'. What's wrong?

Comment: Each div contains only one h1. You want `div:nth-of-type(..) h1` for a selector.

Comment: What you actually want to do, is look into **CSS Counters**. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters

Comment: Added both `nth-of-type` and CSS counter based solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `h1` in your example is `first-of-type` since the counting resets on every new parent `div`, so you need to work with `div:nth-of-type h1::before`.

```css
div h1::before {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: inherit;
  left: 0;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) h1::before {
  content: '01';
  color: #E82F3A;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) h1::before {
  content: '02';
  color: #E82F3A;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) h1::before {
  content: '03';
  color: #E82F3A;
}

div h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: #404C60;
  padding-left: 35px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

If your really want numbers, you can use a CSS counter:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section;
}

div h1::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: inherit;
  left: 0;
  content: "0"counter(section);
  color: #E82F3A;
}

div:nth-of-type(10) h1::before,
div:nth-of-type(10) ~ div h1::before {
  content: counter(section);
}

div h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: #404C60;
  padding-left: 35px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Wooow it's work!! thank you! I really love your answer :)

Comment: Don’t hardcode the leading zero, *use* css: `counter(section, decimal-leading-zero);`

Comment: Will that create `011` instead of `11`? That'd be unwanted as I would only prefix single digit numbers.

Comment: @connexo: It only adds the leading zero to single digits. In fact, in situations where zero padding matters, decimal-leading-zero is only useful from 10 to 99. Starting from 100 it becomes useless because it *only* pads single digits. (But that's mostly because CSS counters can't know how many elements need to be numbered in advance, so they can't automatically adjust the zero padding for the first few items.)

Comment: @BoltClock Is this feature documented anywhere other than in CSS Counters Level 3 Spec by the W3C? I couldn't even find information on it on MDN and caniuse.com.

Comment: @connexo: The closest is CSS2 as referenced by css-counter-styles but CSS2 doesn't really say that it stops at two digits, only that it gives examples up to 99. See also https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Nov/0802.html

Answer (score 1):

You will need the [nth-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) selector. Since your `di`vs are siblings, you could create a CSS rule which would include that and their child. Assuming that the parent of the `div`s has an `id` of `foobar`, an example might be something like this:

```
#foobar :nth-child(3) h1::before {
    /*your rule*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `:first-of-type`, `:nth-of-type`, and `:last-of-type` pseudo-classes refer to the first/nth/last elements *among siblings*. Since your `<h1>`s are each wrapped in their own `<div>`s, they match both `:first-of-type` and `:last-of-type`, and the rule defined later wins.

Instead of dealing with all that, you can use [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters).

```css
.timeline {
  counter-reset: my-counter;
}

.timeline h1::before {
  content: counter(my-counter, decimal-leading-zero);
  counter-increment: my-counter;
}

/* the rest is your original code */
.timeline h1::before {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: inherit;
  left: 0;
  color: #E82F3A;
}

.timeline h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: #404C60;
  padding-left: 35px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Breaking it down:

```
.timeline {
  counter-reset: my-counter;
}
```

We're creating a new counter called `my-counter`. It needs to be initialized before we can use it. [`counter-reset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset) handles that. Every `.timeline` has a `my-counter` counter that starts at 0. We'll be incrementing it in the `h1::before` pseudo-element, so the numbers that actually display start at 1.

```
.timeline h1::before {
  content: counter(my-counter, decimal-leading-zero);
  counter-increment: my-counter;
}
```

Here we set the content of the `h1::before` pseudo-element to the value of our `my-counter` counter and apply the [`decmial-leading-zero` list style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) to it with [`counter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters#Displaying_a_counter). [`counter-increment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-increment) increases the value of `my-counter` by 1 before it is displayed.